# Pymongo find() by filter variable return empty

Tags: python, pymongo, bottle

I code it with python 3, mongodb and bottle.

This code return empty document. I check the `name` which is correctly value.

```
@bottle.route('/test1/<name>', method='GET')
def test_detail(name):
    result = dbcoll.find({"student": name})
    return template('detail',name=result)
```

I modified to hard code the `name` and it can show the result correctly!

```
@bottle.route('/test1/<name>', method='GET')
def test_detail(name):
    name = "peter chan"
    result = dbcoll.find({"student": name})
    return template('detail',name=result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are getting some value in `name` inside function, my instinct is you are getting `None` in that variable.

Comment: Thanks for comment.  I did put `print(name)` before the `find()` and it contains value. Just like what I hard code it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with the space in the name. Generally strings are url-encoded and the space character is transformed into "+". You might want to url-deencode that and use the result in the db query.